# How do react-native apps track installs for Facebook/IG Meta Mobile ads?

Tags: react-native, mobile, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk-next

We need App-installs/conversions event tracking in Meta to optimize our ad delivery. This requires FBSDK to be installed.

Facebook has abandoned the React-Native FBSDK, and the community run FBSDK is abandoned
https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next

This no longer works and has not for a long from what I've read.

Are RN Mobile App Owners just not marketing using Meta's app install campaign objectives? Or is there some other way to make this work that I'm not aware of?

Thank you.

Comment: I am also interested

Comment: Hi @Raven. the issue is that you can't configure the fbsdk-next package?

Comment: I've managed to work with this package. and also do social login using this package. Let me know if you need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there are tools called Mobile Measurement Partners.

The two I've tried are AppsFlyer and Branch.io

They include their own maintained FBSDK along side with SDKs for Twitter, TikTok, and many other popular platforms. So you only have to set this up once, then you are poised to run install campaigns on virtually all platforms.

They work on React Native and have examples for how to set each one up.

I ended up going with AppsFlyer because they have better community support. I liked Branch.io, but unfortunately their support staff don't care at all about helping you, so thats not a very good long-term solution IMO.